# Can't render image in the html page with <img> attribute

Tags: html, image

This is the URL of the image I want to display:
"https://instagram.fbom26-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/56974016_825894781099239_5979086687874056192_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fbom26-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=77CjykitzEgAX9uBl66&edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT_uz-sv6kRkRLCsR2LuPvUQ6mWzrFM8oOlw3VTJAjL-gw&oe=62B3EF2C&_nc_sid=8fd12b"

I tried the below code but its not working:

```
<body>
<img src="https://instagram.fbom26-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/56974016_825894781099239_5979086687874056192_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fbom26-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=77CjykitzEgAX9uBl66&edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT_uz-sv6kRkRLCsR2LuPvUQ6mWzrFM8oOlw3VTJAjL-gw&oe=62B3EF2C&_nc_sid=8fd12b">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this image because this resource is served from same site

`cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin`

**To use this resource from a different origin, the server may relax the cross-origin resource policy response header:**

`Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site`: Choose this option if the resource and the document are served from the same site.

`Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin`: Only choose this option if an arbitrary website including this resource does not impose a security risk.

There's not much you can do in this case because this option has to be set on the server side

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy`

Because the resource serve from same site.

Best you can do is to download the image locally or to your host.